# How to get ASIN and price from AMAZON

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have the detail information of books including ISBN, title, and author, is there anyway to get ASIN and the price so that i could make links to the product page on amazon directly?Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 10 digit ISBN numbers, the ASIN number is actually the same.

[What are UPCs, EANs, ISBNs. and ASINs?](http://www.amazon.com/gp/seller/asin-upc-isbn-info.html)

> Amazon Standard Identification Numbers (ASINs) are unique blocks of 10
>   letters and/or numbers that identify items. You can find the ASIN on
>   the item's product information page at Amazon.com. **For books, the ASIN
>   is the same as the ISBN number**, but for all other products a new ASIN
>   is created when the item is uploaded to our catalogue.

[how do i get an ASIN number?](http://askville.amazon.com/ASIN-number/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=52827992)

> Each product sold on Amazon.com is given a unique ASIN. **For books
>   with 10-digit ISBN, the ASIN and the ISBN are the same.** Books
>   without an ISBN and other products are also assigned ASINs.

With the ASIN known, you can then use the [ItemLookup Amazon API command](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) to retrieve the price.

Comment: i am also finding this solution. First link is not working. And how to use second link.